# API image request returned weird characters. How do I display image?

Tags: image, api

I got an image through API request, and I got

```
  Array
(
    [code] => 200
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [cache-control] => maxage=15552000
            [content-type] => image/png
            [date] => Thu, 05 Apr 2012 02:14:10 GMT
            [expires] => Tue, 02 Oct 2012 02:14:11 GMT
            [p3p] => CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
            [pragma] => public
            [server] => Apache
            [set-cookie] => CAKEPHP=ni9r4qo9ia4a0os2; expires=Sun, 05-Apr-2037 08:14:10 GMT; path=/; domain=.somedomain.com
            [vary] => Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
            [content-length] => 4303
            [connection] => keep-alive
        )
```

```
[body] => ‰PNG
```

IHDRôôî½€V  pHYsHHFÉk>  vpAgôôL´£<�
IDATxÚí?¯ãÆGÆ3ì ÿ¼k'¤ZìA z°HŠ)\°w³.÷,ÀÊíøâ‚ö'PÂüB$Ž
öªÕ)€BRÚ·Zk†œ¯æÍêžShõÞÓ½;Ô)Jäðgv sß€ø ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒ‚t… ]!HWÒr$}[gæ^X4òË%¼,Y½½oS‚I¯M±jî:7éÅ^–Uaêû6%È‘ô¬¸¯AÌKéŽùB¸a‘Ez.bp$Ý¬îke.¾XÒË²º¦ŸcéÍ}
¢’—.½,
Ò…Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\îÒ¥Az\&K—Hâ@z\&IßÖÅÜ˜¬œšjWzaæû;+óòas3e‚ôÛ.©OEš˜þWzëz¿y*©ú;3šËƒô=›ÌÌ»¨”æîÉ;—¸Ò·Æ,û;íVjÿ/ÛV!}ÏÌd‡§ª0Ó‚r"¿§ç¦ÏrÚ˜ùl/{aF€ôÃÓpW°­ÂJJdéK3ÛÿS,ö/ÖÙaÕ\Zé!Þ#çK¯ŒXTYdé›ýËuaêÚt‰pODzÏÂˆÞÅþÈ6ï÷AÚmû¦ß‘¯^îÎ€ôžùÄ½·#bK/»TÓÝÌ»u<7ã    HïÉÞ\é«no½ìTwªÛ~7t=¼ÿŽôžÓ]Þª[mJ³Ûæ£#7k5gêUûµê÷ëòá
¤÷¿n¿YvÏç./R—¾0å¶ÿl¾m…—ýÎI¾ZíÍ!ýð4Ü}µÍæ]mµÈv«EÛ±I]zmæÍþÃGfÖó~9òy9[-­ôï‘ _Îäæå³TìïUU¶.ê7Azû¡­Øï’”íþ[¾ÚåŸÖ‘¾§}æLÕì6Ëì°ÎWÕ²˜ïÞé»îˆAÿ¦;|ÐÝi·U¤Ónì÷ã«jcŠ¶c³Ìš ãnñ¥Wí <ŒÞä+6ï>l—yë}^
ëzW®wù.oY‡ô‰/}ç‡Ïæåa¬y½:Ò†ti8‰".H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.H÷éÒ =.ÇÒëóÛL#4¼oœÙh6v õ•J_ˆ?õžlå_nÅxNr¹X„tIoÌ¼¬îÂÌ‚½|X›™ä²”³û{ï»Ç[­M™ßµ¸óvY*Ñ!V›éCJ‡kz«O®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®Uúja‚˜ÍKÝ.çaóZd`3ûÀ6Õ,¬ÏbõªøJ¥¯Úç¼  ¡œ\’¡˜A
[¹6ëMèÀªYfN6«‚ÚÔùÑû+•~U•\Õ7áWË(2ß_Ò˜õé/×áIÈŠ»»W*ýŒš?g\hhe+É«à>sKI~y•£«9]«ôF¸äét[É×ãBzp  ÒÓéC%H÷+Azú }¨é~%HO¤• Ý¯éé#'ýp5Ë©Ò·‡>S¥¾6Dº…3¤?þ¯õ×Õ£ÛîPÅwƒþð‡£óY5Ô?Ügq{ôÃ§Ëî[ÙÛðë#ÝVò­õ×•1æá‹Õ·×ô¦;ÒõñróäŒ5ýó£þÖ¶ytÛ|Îš~ŠKú6w.ðØ±ÉÝÿ¬eë,w©il]~î’^×¡˜ÜzàÖµÎC1z¥W…[º{Moù…CúvÑ¸"
N×tsc8¤—åz¶²ÿédMoyÇ%};Ÿ¹]­ô²³7ïGŠDØæ}³ÌW@Ú¼—eîXt¤[8wGn9slÞÃväêÜ•@²#×Ì·H?a`M·—Œ}d[çkÇ_‚>²µ¯ˆÌµyøÈ–ÏóYf^éuaª&¬dSzVTU@‰Kz>[87ï_Î¬›&[Úû(–^U²Ò7]ÄK@‰óË™ué
5   üF®v¼Ûè•~v  _Ã¦Ò‡JîW‚ôôAúP  ÒýJž>H*¹VéLv8)¹zéLk:áú§5
M`ü^rã¿»›ÿLžÀøCwóãô Œ?Þ5S8Ñ1#ø÷ÝÍ{’S•?èn~;yªòƒîæÝéS•ß½k¦pª²“?™Õô&Ç¬ÍC‘>OeBäkótüAÊ¤¯y.ÛñÖˆ¼Œ6Æ<“N»OýV&½º1d;>2æ…@›å11ò[cn–£R&ý©‘Y1ïXwg²ôÉÚ>Û÷º;?gôQº¤oº]‰óŽ²]CÍzr›~`o<Ï»>£Ûw]Ò—oug¼Iv|Ü=Ë·“ÛÔÝkGà§Ûq¿Ýbè’žõŸ^¦¯˜wôk¨ùãä>Ïú>“ßxV}›Ñ=B]Ò›¦1M3¾{ëÍ¶oØ¤2°ßptI¿ÄK5êãÓé©4Dúå@:ÒÓiˆôËt¤§Óé—éHO§!Ò/Ò‘žNC¤*¤*¯ôðsäFNa:G®)¬gÂ
ÌqŽœu8ïÝ5û)EóªøJ¥'|6lv6lé:¶;6»þ³aÅÏ{ßrÞ{ò`†KðlÌp‰sÙ†JîW‚ôôAúP  ÒýJž>H*Aº_  ÒÓéC%H÷+Azú\mœÇ¡
Ò-ˆÆyt_ƒ~>‹å‡~hÌ³ýU ¿
îCœ‡'iÆy|VÄyÜ˜öeHœ‡gœÇâüd;Cq¯ýÐáNvØ•ÆµòÚ’~EœÇ)Î%>‚#Î#ˆó°àÊp)
wœ‡õh½c)¶q'œçñà¹DœÇÍpœGíçñbEœ‡Á8ö
½ýç»'®:wœÇë;rŸ-»Ç¹ã<2¿8ý~%qäâ<6#u›L$ÎcEœÇd\Ò×Kãš~nœÇÒ5œ8È¼yq
qSákØ¡¤û• =}>T‚t¿¤§Ò‡JîW‚ôô¹¦8Ì&=x¢ŒéWçÑxþr˜ëŸÖ´2‹•ôFëŒÁO`tÇyXVÍíçÖ8ï5ÄyÔÖ’ý$Þ÷f¿Â17øòq¥}ªrIœ‡7ÄyìÔI'Î£C™ôêFörïýß§_î8K’tœ‡ÀÀº¾çñ:ÉÆyl»IÅyŒn1tIïã<$VÌ;>éže8~¯{úpúwâ<^ƒ8]Òâ<:tI¿ÄsñÀôA:ÒÓiˆôËt¤§Óé—éHO§!Ò/Ò‘žNC¤_¤#=†HŸLç±‹ó¨­çÈ}èH*Aº_   ÒÓ'½8Ã¿Äy\Á8Ç¢q óøâµ«@?]öWþ"¸
Òm%îë½?º•ŠóØJÄy<.‰ó°!çñK÷¥¿â<Œy_"Îã†8ñâ<²•Xœ‡ã QPœÇŽ8SÎŒó¨ÿ)çñt(Îcåçñ8+’qÏeâ<>>;ÎãË£>m÷/Ú¾$Îã”ˆqs‘8†8ÉÄ‹óÈ¥â<
â<&òÆyÄyL„¯a‡JîW‚ôôAúP  ÒýJž>H*Aº_  ÒÓçŒëðçñ¦“_OœÇÚç|ÙËëŸÖçQÍG^&‹Ð8Â1Ñ:°¡8ë¦y`œÇjqýƒã<©¯ŽóÈê­ÿÀ.çqœ.r­Ò]$çñ‘TœÇGãR&}-|¹÷îŒ—3>)œBœÇåX¦ç!1âJ—ôþšü¥dÇŠ8Ôéã<Â/â0À'2/#â<.q=º¤7Äytè’~‰æâéƒt¤§Óé—éHO§!Ò/Ò‘žNC¤_¤#=†H¿HGz:
‘>{jÆÏº›·mñˆóÈœß±ý%(ÎãÝÐm—ÖSöÞvžk§ Î£1Yåâ¶_úÄyØê¾én¾²ýÅç±¶¬Ó×ö9â<¬ÃùÚ¹€ÙÑÁÅ+•žnœGðÑ|©8ùÕŸ÷NœÇiÉÕÏpa.ÛP  ÒýJž>H*Aº_  ÒÓéC%H÷+Azú }¨é~%HO¤• ý%O\qeçñ$¬[Ë÷ýÐ¼ÿ¼¿HÁ_§Çyt_çaA2ÎãÆ<º]‹Äy<“ˆóxË<%ÎÃŠxœÇï„â<~#çñkâT‚t¿¤§Ò‡JîW‚ôôAúPÉµJ'Îã¤äê¥ç‹ÐŠ‘€â<Ò§6…3ÎÃŠGœGÔ0,ÎÃÍÒç±ŽŠ8Ìáç1ëç10°ÂçQGsœì®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºB®¤+é
AºBþçL™@ùE¯‘%tEXtdate:create2012-04-05T01:46:01+00:00>—O%tEXtdate:modify2012-04-05T01:46:01+00:00pc/óIEND®B`‚
)

How can I display this image in a regular webpage?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characters was the image in a binary data format.

To display this data as image I did the following:

I saved the characters in a file (used notepad++ text editor) and I saved the file with a .png extension.

```
$imgfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/charts/".$_GET['documentId'].".png";
$imglink = "http://domain.com/images/charts/".$_GET['documentId'].".png";
$imgfilehandle = fopen($imgfile, 'w') or die('COULD NOT OPEN FILE: '.$imgfile);
fwrite($imgfilehandle, $result['body']);
fclose($imgfilehandle);
```

then in the body of the html document I displayed the image through this code

```
    function data_uri($imgfile, $mime) {

    $contents = file_get_contents($imgfile);
    $base64 = base64_encode($contents);
    return "data:$mime;base64,$base64";

    }

<img id="thischart" class="chart" style="margin: 0 auto; min-height: 1px; min-width: 1px; position: relative; " src="<?php echo data_uri($imgfile, 'image/png');?>" />
```

voila...